# Exchange 2013 Client Frontend connector will not accept TLS

Tags: smtp, exchange-2013

I have a new Exchange 2013 environment running on Windows 2013 R2 with 2x Edge and 4x CAS/Mailbox servers deployed. It is deployed in a resource forest, with proper trust relationships established to the primary forest. OWA, ActiveSync, and IMAP all work great.

For those clients that don't/won't work with ActiveSync, I of course need IMAP and SMTP (we're consciously giving a flat "no" to POP). IMAP is working fine; SMTP is not.

The default receive connector Client Frontend is configured to listen on port 587. When I disable TLS in e.g. Mac Mail (behavior's virtually identical regardless of client), I'm able to login only with users in the resource forest -- I cannot authenticate users in the primary forest. If I enable TLS (which is what I want, and what the settings seem to indicate), I can't connect at all.

Interestingly, the Client Proxy default receive connector (on port 465) *does* work, with TLS enabled and authenticating primary forest users. This tells me that the SSL certificate is fine, as well as the trust is functioning.

I can't figure out why the Client Frontend connector will not let me connect over TLS. When I use Telnet, I get the following introduction:

```
Trying x.x.x.86...
Connected to excmb1.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 example.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 6 Aug 2014 15:51:27 -0800
ehlo
250-example.com Hello [x.x.x.155]
250-SIZE 36700160
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH GSSAPI NTLM
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250 CHUNKING
quit
221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I can't help but notice the lack of the "250-STARTTLS" line there -- it *is* present when I Telnet to port 465.

Using the EMC and the `Get-ReceiveConnector` cmdlet, the two receive connectors are essentially identical. So why won't the one on 587 -- the one that clients are supposed to use for SMTP -- not work over TLS nor authenticate trusted domain users? Why does one receive connector -- the one that's supposed to just be for the Exchange servers to talk to each other -- work, while a seemingly-identical one not?

Answer (score 2):

First check whether the Tls AuthMechanism is enabled on the connector:

```
Get-ReceiveConnector -Identity "SERVER\Default Frontend SERVER" | Format-List
```

If this is not the case, enable it:

```
Set-ReceiveConnector -Identity "SERVER\Default Frontend SERVER" -AuthMechanism "None,Tls"
```

Then also make sure that you have a certificate for the Smtp service registered:

```
Get-ExchangeCertificate | Format-List
```

Finally verify everything:
http://www.checktls.com/index.html